# Building credit history later in life

Tags: united-states, credit-score, auto-loan

I am trying to build credit so in the future I could get a loan if needed probably a car loan. I’m 39 years old.I have never had a mortgage,credit card, or any type of loan in my name just household utilities. My credit score is 568, with 1 derogatory mark of $202 from 5+ years ago. I was going to fight the 202.00 but it may just be easier & quicker to just repay it. I’m not sure what would be the best way to increase my credit score over time. Should I get one of those credit building credit cards, or try to get the minimum loan amount at my bank ( probably with a co-signer ) put the loan in a separate savings acct & just have the bank automatically take the payments out? Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There have been past questions about credit scores. Have you reviewed those yet?

Comment: "Should I get one of those credit building credit cards"?  If those are secured credit cards, then sure.  *Any* kind of credit card will help.

Comment: Just, for God's sake **pay it on time** and don't let your usage go beyond 30%.  Banking apps make it easy to pay cards throughout the month.

Comment: Before you put effort into building credit, go to a lender and ask how much you could borrow if you wanted and at what rate. You may not need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build your credit history/score you need somebody to extend you credit. There is no need to pay interest. Start with a credit card, start using it and then over time your situation should improve.

Some people find that they can't get a perfect score unless they also have now, or recently had, a car loan or mortgage.  Those will cost you money. You don't need to start with a loan that costs you money.

Get a credit card, a secured one if that is all you can get, and then use it. Pay it off before the due date. Don't pay late. Don't make only a partial payment.

Some people will tell you to not go above 30% utilization. While that is good advice, you may find that if you do go over that 30% utilization, and show you can pay it off they will increase your credit limit. In that situation the increased limit will help your score.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I’m gonna try to get a secured card  after I start my new job in the spring. I did however pay off the only bad mark on my history not to long ago. Thanks again.